# How to get the type on which a MemberExpression is invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Imagine the following classes:

```
class A
{
    public string Test {get; set;}
}
class B : A
{
    .. some other members ..
}
```

Now I am given a MemberExpression that was created from something similar to `instance.Test`
where `instance` is of type B.

Using the `MemberExpression.Member.DeclaringType` property returns that the declariny type of the Test-Property is class A - of course.

However, is there any way to get to know that the Test-property was originally invoked on type B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does `MemberExpression.Expression.Type` do what you want?

Comment: That's exactly what i've been looking for. Thank you!!